# JavaScript : Time and date

Tags: javascript, date, time

I took the date and time example from w3schools and rearranged the code. However, it is not working.

**The original code:**

```
<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = Date()">
Click me to display Date and Time.</button>
```

**My version:**

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("button").onclick = function() {

       document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Date();

    }
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to set the button id to "button"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the demo and the id of the button:

```js
document.getElementById("button").onclick = function() {

       document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Date();

}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="button">
Click me to display Date and Time.</button>
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: I didn't paste them here. It's my first comment here.                                                    
    <p id="demo">Date and time!</p>
    <p><button type="button">Click me to display Date and Time</button></p>

Comment: @VeraKatic Then the issue is with the ``id`` of the ``button``

Comment: OMG!!! I just realized I didn't add id for the button!                                                            It is working now!!!!! Thank you very much.